# Limit involving a trigonometric function as $x\rightarrow +\infty$

Tags: calculus

I am probably supposed to use this identity: $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$ 
I have this mathematical problem:
$$\lim_{x\to+∞} (x^2-1) \sin(\frac{1}{x-1}) = \lim_{x\to+∞} (x+1)(x-1) \sin(\frac{1}{x-1}) = ???$$
Can I do this to the sinus limit?
$$\lim_{x\to+∞} \frac{1}{\sin(\frac{x-1}{1})}$$

Comment: No. Put $X=\frac{1}{x-1}$ and make $X\to 0$

Comment: @Abdallah Hammam But what about the (x+1) limit? As it is now it'll be either positive infinity or as you suggested zero

Comment: $x=\frac{1}{X}+1$, so $x+1=...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\frac{1}{x-1}$ so that $x-1=\frac{1}{X}$ and $x+1=2+\frac{1}{X}$
We have $\lim_{x \to +\infty} (x^2-1) \sin(\frac{1}{x-1})=\lim_{X \to 0^+} (2+\frac{1}{X}) \frac{\sin(X)}{X}=+\infty$

Answer (score 0):

With $X=\frac{1}{x-1}$ or

$x=\frac{1}{X}+1$,

the limit becomes,

$\lim_{X\to 0^+}(\frac{1}{X}+2)\frac{\sin(X)}{X}$

wich gives $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin t \sim t$  when $t \to 0$, we  have $\sin \frac{1}{x-1} \sim \frac{1}{x-1} \sim \frac 1x$ when $x \to +\infty$. We have also  $x^2-1 \sim x^2$ when $x \to +\infty$. Using this, we have  $f(x)=(x^2-1)\sin\frac{1}{x-1} \sim x$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=+\infty$